# Possible to use Iterative FD methods to solve a transformed non square domain [matlab]?

Tags: matlab, finite-difference, fluid-dynamics, iterative-method, poisson

For the 2-D Poisson equation $$-(u_{xx}+u_{yy}) = f \ \ \text{where} f = 1$$

For boundary conditions
$$\frac{\partial u}{\partial n} = 0 \ \text{on AB and AD}$$
$$ u = 0 \ \ \ \text{on BC and CD no-slip condition}$$

I know how to solve this using both a Gauss Siedel and Jacobian method for normal problems however, what if the domain is an irregular shape such as.

[image]

I've solved this in class using a transformation of variables and using the Matrix method but it was a pain in the `ass`

[image]

The transformation is
$$ x = m\xi \\ y = h \eta+s \xi - s\eta \xi $$
Where
$$ h = 1 s = 0.5 m = 0.866$$
I can post the full math for transforming if interested but the transformed poisson equation is

$$-1/J^2 (au_{\xi \xi} - 2bu_{\xi\eta} + cu_{\eta \eta} + du_{\eta}+eu_\xi)$$
$$\text{Where} \ \ u_\xi \text{ is discretized like } u_x$$
Full Discretization scheme is like

[image]

and the coefficients

[image]

The left and right boundary conditions discretized

[image]

[image]

I put together a jacobi scheme like this

$$u^{k+1}_{ij} = \frac{1}{2*h_{\xi\eta}} *\{a\Delta \eta^2(u_{i+1,j}+u_{i-1,j})+c\Delta \xi^2
(u_{i,j+1}+u_{i,j-1}) + \\
[2d\Delta \xi(u_{i,j+1}-u_{i,j-1}) - 2b(u_{i+1,j+1}+u_{i-1,j-1}-u_{i-1,j+1}-u_{u+1,j-1})]\frac{\Delta \xi \Delta \eta}{4} \\
+ J^2f_{i,j} \Delta xi^2 \Delta \eta^2 \}$$
$$ h_{ \xi \eta} = \Delta \xi^2 + \Delta \eta^2$$

I've iterated about 1000 times but my results don't align with the expected
[image: 'My results']

And the expected results

[image]

I think I maybe having issues implementing the boundary conditions so here's my code, but if it's not possible to do this iteratively then just let me know. THANK YOU

````
%% Initiate Variables 
N = 21; 

l = 3; 
s = 0.5; 
h = 1; 

m = sqrt((1/2*l-h+s)^2-s^2); 
x = linspace(0,m,N); 
y = linspace(0,h,N); 

dx = x(2)-x(1); dy = y(2)-y(1); 

%% Map coordinates to the xi and nu 

xi = x/m; 
nu = (m.*y-s.*x)./(m*h-s.*x); 

dxi = xi(2)-xi(1); %these should be the same i think 
dnu = nu(2)-nu(1); 

hx = dxi.^2; 
hn = dnu.^2; 
hh = dxi*dnu; %multipy non squared
hhxn = hn*hx; 
hxn = hx+hn; %adding the squres
w = 2/3; 
%% Solve the poisson equation I guess ? 

u = zeros(N,N); 
uj = u; 
f = u; 

J = m*(h-s*xi); 
a = (h-s.*xi).^2; 
b = s*(1-nu).*(h-s.*xi); 
c = m^2+s^2*(1-nu).^2; 
e = 0; 
af = 0; 
beta = 2*s^2*(1-nu).*(h-s.*xi); 
d = -2*s.^2*(1-nu); 

gam = (s*(1-nu))./(h-s*xi); 

f(1:N,1:N) = 1; 

%% Jacobi for transformed index 

for k = 1:100
    
    uo = u; 
    
    
    for j = 2:N-1
        for i= 2:N-1
            
          
                dudxi2 = uo(i+1,j) + uo(i-1,j); 
                dudn2 = uo(i,j+1)+uo(i,j-1); 
            
                dudx = uo(i+1,j) - uo(i-1,j); 
                dudn = uo(i,j+1)-uo(i,j-1); 
            
                dudxn = uo(i+1,j+1)+uo(i-1,j-1)+uo(i-1,j+1)-uo(i+1,j-1); 
            
                u(i,j) = ( 1/(2*hxn)*(a(i)*hn*dudxi2 + c(j)*hx*dudn2 + ...
                    (2*d(j)*dxi*dudn  + 2*b(i)*dudxn)*(hh/4)) ... 
                    + (J(i)^2*f(i,j)*hhxn)/(hxn));
                
            end
       
            
    end
        
    end
    

%% Boundary conditions 

% for k = 1:100
%     uo = u; 
% for j = 2:N-1
%     
%     i = 1; 
%     k1 = dxi/dnu*gam(j)*(uo(i,j+1) - uo(i,j-1))-uo(i+1,j); 
%     
%     dudxi2 = uo(i+1,j) + uo(i-1,j); 
%             dudn2 = uo(i,j-1)+uo(i,j-1); 
%             
%             dudx = uo(i+1,j) - k1; 
%             dudn = 0; 
%             
%             dudxn = uo(i+1,j-1)+uo(i-1,j-1)+uo(i-1,j-1)-uo(i+1,j-1); 
%             
%             u(i,j) = 1/(2*hxn)*(a(i)*hn*dudxi2 + c(j)*hx*dudn2 + ...
%                 (2*d(j)*dxi*dudn  + 2*b(i)*dudxn)*(hh/4)) ... 
%                 + (J(i,j)^2*f(i,j)*hhxn)/(hxn); 
%     
% end
% end
% 
% for k = 1:100
%     uo = u; 
%     for i = 2:N-1
%         j = N; 
%         dudxi2 = uo(i+1,j) + uo(i-1,j); 
%             dudn2 = uo(i,j-1)+uo(i,j-1); 
%             
%             dudx = uo(i+1,j) - uo(i-1,j); 
%             dudn = 0; 
%             
%             dudxn = uo(i+1,j-1)+uo(i-1,j-1)+uo(i-1,j-1)-uo(i+1,j-1); 
%             
%             u(i,j) = 1/(2*hxn)*(a(i)*hn*dudxi2 + c(j)*hx*dudn2 + ...
%                 (2*d(j)*dxi*dudn  + 2*b(i)*dudxn)*(hh/4)) ... 
%                 + (J(i,j)^2*f(i,j)*hhxn)/(hxn); 
%     end
% end
%         

%% plot

figure()
contour(x,y,u)

for i = 1:N
    for j = 1:N
        xi2 = (i-1)*dx; 
        nu2 = (j-1)*dy; 
        X(i,j) = m*xi2; 
        Y(i,j) = h*nu2 + s*xi2 - s*nu2*xi2; 
    end
end
umax = max(max(max(abs(u))))

figure()
contour(X,Y,u'); 

figure,
mesh(X,Y,0*X,0*Y); 
view([0,0,1]); 
axis equal 

figure,
    patch([0,m,m,0],[0,s,h,h],-ones(1,4),0,'facecolor',[0.8,.8,.8]); 
    hold on 
    [ccc,fff] = contour(X,Y,abs(u),(0.02:0.02:max(max(max(abs(u)))))'); 
    clabel(ccc,fff)
    axis equal
    hold off 
            
    ```
````

Comment: Why do you use the analytical expression for the transformation? This complicates the whole stuff. Simply approximate the metric terms analog to $u$.

Answer (score 1):

**A hint for you:**

Starting from the Poisson equation

\begin{align}
    u_{xx} + u_{yy} &= f \quad \text{in} ~~ \Omega , \\
    u  & = 0 \quad \text{in} ~~ \partial \Omega ,\\
\frac{\partial u}{\partial n} &= 0 \quad \text{in} ~~ \partial \Omega.
\end{align}

You can use following **general** relation

\begin{equation}
            \underbrace{\begin{pmatrix}
            x_{\xi} & y_{\xi} & 0 & 0 & 0 \\             
            x_{\eta} & y_{\eta} & 0 & 0 & 0 \\              
              x_{\xi\xi} &   y_{\xi\xi}  & x_{\xi}^2  & y_{\xi}^2 & 2 x_{\xi} y_{\xi} \\
              x_{\eta\eta} &   y_{\eta\eta}  & x_{\eta}^2  & y_{\eta}^2 & 2 x_{\eta} y_{\eta} \\
              x_{\xi\eta} &  y_{\xi\eta} & x_{\eta} x_{\xi} & y_{\eta} y_{\xi} &  x_{\eta} y_{\xi} + x_{\xi} y_{\eta}                          
        \end{pmatrix}}_{\underline{\underline{M}}} \cdot 
        \begin{pmatrix}
        \partial_{x}   \\
        \partial_{y} \\
         \partial_{xx}^2 \\
         \partial_{yy}^2 \\
        \partial_{x}\partial_{y} \\     
        \end{pmatrix} =
        \begin{pmatrix}
            \partial_{\xi}   \\
             \partial_{\eta} \\          
             \partial_{\xi\xi}^2 \\
             \partial_{\eta\eta}^2 \\
            \partial_{\xi}\partial_{\eta}
        \end{pmatrix}.
\end{equation}

Do **not** use the analytical expression for the transformation. Instead discretisize the Metric terms

\begin{align}
x_{\xi~(i,j)}   \approx  \frac{x_{i+1,j} - x_{i-1,j}}{2\Delta\xi}, \quad\quad & y_{\xi~(i,j)}  \approx  \frac{y_{i+1,j} - y_{i-1,j}}{2\Delta\xi} \\
x_{\eta~(i,j)}  \approx  \frac{x_{i,j+1} - x_{i,j-1}}{2\Delta\eta}, \quad\quad & y_{\eta~(i,j)}  \approx  \frac{y_{i,j+1} - y_{i,j-1}}{2\Delta\eta} \\
\dots
\end{align}

Use **one-side stencils** at the boundaries.

Now simply invert the matrix with $\underline{\underline{M}}^{-1} = \underline{\underline{W}}$

\begin{align}
  \underline{\underline{M}} \cdot \underline{\partial_{\boldsymbol{x}}} &=
  \underline{\partial_{\boldsymbol{\xi}}} ,\\
 \underline{\partial_{\boldsymbol{x}}} &=
   \underline{\underline{W}} \cdot \underline{\partial_{\boldsymbol{\xi}}},
\end{align}

resulting in

\begin{eqnarray}
 a u_{\xi\xi} + b  u_{\xi\eta} + c  u_{\eta\eta}  + d  u_{\xi} + e  u_{\eta} = f,
    \label{eq:dgl_trafo}
\end{eqnarray}

where $a$, $b$, $c$, $d$, $e$ are point wise values which can be used directly on each DOF $(i,j)$. To build up $a$, $b$, $c$, $d$, $e$ you only need column 3 and 4 of $\underline{\underline{W}}$, guess why?

**Works on arbitrary meshes!**

The rest is quite simple and similar to the Cartesian case. Simply discretisize $u$ and use a Gauss-Seidel or SOR method.

Regards

Answer (score 0):

To directly answer your question. Yes, it is possible, but it gets complicated as one needs to keep track of coordinate changes, and the local metric. I have not checked in detail if the analytical formulation of the Laplacian you have is correct for your coordinate system. I did check the boundary condition, and it seems to be correct.

I notice in your code you compute your grid in with constant $dx$ and $dy$ and then, it seems, assume $d\xi$ and $d\eta$ are also constant. In one or the other coordinate systems they are not having constant spacing.

I did calculate the boundary conditions and I get the following along $AC$ which I think is the same as your discretized version. (Substitute $\xi=x/m$ to compare with your equation).

\begin{equation}
\frac{\partial u}{\partial n} = \nabla u\cdot (-\mathbf{e}_{x}) = - \left(- \frac{s}{m \left(h - \frac{s x}{m}\right)} + \frac{s \left(y - \frac{s x}{m}\right)}{m \left(h - \frac{s x}{m}\right)^{2}}\right) \frac{\partial}{\partial \eta} u{\left(\xi,\eta \right)} - \frac{\frac{\partial}{\partial \xi} u{\left(\xi,\eta \right)}}{m}
\end{equation}

After factoring this is the same
\begin{equation}
\frac{\partial u}{\partial n} = \frac{s(1-\eta)}{m(h-s\xi)}\frac{\partial}{\partial \eta} u{\left(\xi,\eta \right)} - \frac{\frac{\partial}{\partial \xi} u{\left(\xi,\eta \right)}}{m}
\end{equation}

The following is not an essential problem.

<s>I think your coordinate change does not work the way you think it does. I'm not sure exactly the derivation in your mind, but at I think $\eta=0$ the idea is that $\xi$ parameterizes the lower boundary $BC$. Then similarly as you move up the figure, $\xi$ parameterizes straight curves from $AB$ to $CD$, but these are not all of the same slope if "evenly" distributed, clearly for $\eta=1$ the curve $AC$ is parallel to the $x$-axis while for $\eta=0$ $BC$ is not.</s>

For the coordinate change you give, $\frac{\partial x}{\partial \xi} = m$ for all values of $\eta$, but if the intention is as above this should also depend on $\eta$. If you think of the slope of these lines as having a smoothly varying angle $\theta(\eta)$ such that $\tan \theta(0) = \frac{s}{m}$ and $\tan \theta(1) = 0$ then one should get the coordinate transform

\begin{aligned}
x &= \xi \cos \theta(\eta) \\
y &= h\eta + m\xi\sin \theta(\eta) 
\end{aligned}

The trignometric value may be found by assuming the base remains $m$ for all $\eta$ while the height gained across the domain decreases linearly with $\eta$ as $s(1-\eta)$ gives a hypotenuse of $h^2=(s(1-\eta))^2 + m^2$ then $\cos \theta = \frac{m}{h}$ and $\sin \theta = \frac{s(1-\eta)}{h}$.

Then the transformation would be:
\begin{aligned}
x&= \frac{m \xi}{\left(m^{2} + s^{2} \left(1 - \eta\right)^{2}\right)^{0.5}} \\
y&=\eta h + \frac{m s \xi \left(1 - \eta\right)}{\left(m^{2} + s^{2} \left(1 - \eta\right)^{2}\right)^{0.5}}
\end{aligned}

Comment: No my coordinate change was taken straight out of a textbook $$x \text{ is only a function of } \xi \text{ where as } y \text{ is a function of both}$$